# I can't get coinmarketcap library working

Tags: python, shared-libraries

First I installed the coinmarketcap from the pycharm project interpreter.

Then I run the code below:

```
>>> from coinmarketcap import Market
>>> coinmarketcap = Market()
>>> coinmarketcap.ticker(<currency>, limit=3, convert='EUR')
```

But I got this:

> ImportError: cannot import name Market

Then I thought it is not the right library, so I installed the following API from https://github.com/mrsmn/coinmarketcap-api thinking that pycharm might have installed some other library.

So I downloaded the library from Github and I used the python setup.py install command and installed the library from Github without any problems.

I tried to rerun the code, but the problem still persists:

> ImportError: cannot import name Market

Comment: This error still persists today. I have been followed the instruction to use pip3 install. Everything install fine but still get the error of not finding Market.

Answer (score 0):

I have finally solved it. Actually I needed to uninstall it within pycharm. Then I installed it using the pip install coinmarketcap and after that it works.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score -1):

[image]

I have installed it using pip and tried to import it and did not get any error.so, can you check whether the installation is done with out any error

Comment: Thank you Kalyan Reddy. I  have installed and using many libraries. I did not encounter any errors during the install. That is why I am asking what other things could be wrong. Thank you.